# partitioning by data mysql

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have table 'items'. 18 mln records:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `log_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `res_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `n_date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nd_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `s_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `not_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `link_2` (`link`),
  KEY `log_id` (`log_id`),
  KEY `res_id` (`res_id`),
  KEY `now_date` (`not_date`),
  KEY `sql_index` (`res_id`,`id`,`not_date`)
) ENGINE=Aria  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PAGE_CHECKSUM=0 AUTO_INCREMENT=18382133 ;
```

Trying to partition this table I created a mini copy of it and include column 'not_date' in primary and uniq keys:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `part_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `log_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `res_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `n_date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nd_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `s_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `not_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`not_date`,`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `link_2` (`not_date`,`link`),
  KEY `log_id` (`log_id`),
  KEY `res_id` (`res_id`),
  KEY `now_date` (`not_date`),
  KEY `sql_index` (`res_id`,`id`,`not_date`)
) ENGINE=Aria  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PAGE_CHECKSUM=0
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE ( TO_DAYS(not_date))
(PARTITION p_1 VALUES LESS THAN (735963) ENGINE = Aria,
 PARTITION p_2 VALUES LESS THAN (736694) ENGINE = Aria) */ AUTO_INCREMENT=18414661 ;
```

Then I run sql_query:

```
alter table `part_items` PARTITION BY RANGE( TO_DAYS(not_date) ) (
PARTITION p_1 VALUES LESS THAN( TO_DAYS('2014-12-31') ),
PARTITION p_2 VALUES LESS THAN( TO_DAYS('2016-12-31') )
);
```

Then I trying to select records that must de in p_1 and explain partitions show me that searching was only in p_1. But when I select records that must be in p_2 explain partitions show full-scan(p_1,p_2).
What wrong in my code?
Queries:

```
explain partitions SELECT * FROM `part_items` where content like '%k%' and not_date < '2014-05-12'

explain partitions SELECT * FROM `part_items` where content like '%k%' and not_date > '2015-01-01'
```

And one more question: Is it possible to partitioning views? 
[image]

Comment: add the explain output please

Comment: i have edit question, there explain output

Comment: Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

When `PARTITIONing` by some date function, there is a chance of an invalid date being provided.  That would lead to `NULL`; such values are stored in the *first* partition.

This is an issue that has tripped up many a developer.  The typical 'workaround' is to have the first partition empty so that the effort of looking in it is (usually) minimal.  In your case:

```
PARTITION p_0 VALUES LESS THAN(0)
```

Partitioning on less than about 6 partitions is usually not worth the effort; will you be adding more partitions?

(Caveat:  My advice comes from years of MyISAM/InnoDB partitioning; I don't know of Aria works differently.  I suspect that partitioning is *mostly* handled at then Engine-independent layer.)

Comment: Rick James, thank you very mach! Adding the PARTITION p_0 VALUES LESS THAN(0) realy help me!